# ARM64 SIMD function bottlenecked by simple subtract command?

Tags: assembly, optimization, simd, arm64

I have a function whose signature is `void aggregate(const char *string, int64_t length, void *dest)` and whose goal is to map each char in `string` to the corresponding bit in `dest`, where the bit is 1 if that char is `'\"'` and 0 otherwise. So if the string is `"\"aaaaaa\"...`, then `0b10000001...` is written into `dest`. This function processes 32 bytes from `string` at a time, so `length` is required to be a multiple of that.

Anyways, I have a working function, but according to my profiling, it spends over 80% of its time on the `subs` instruction. I know that you have to be careful about doing processing on normal registers alongside SIMD ones, but I can't figure out why this is such a bottleneck. I also tried doing `cmp` with the current string pointer and the end of the string, and only looping if the current pointer is less than the end. However, this did not help. I also tried unrolling so that I'd run half or a quarter as many `subs` instructions, but that didn't help either. Any ideas?

```
#define vadds_raw v0
#define vadds vadds_raw##.16b
#define vrepquote v1.16b
#define vchrs0_raw v2
#define vchrs0 vchrs0_raw##.16b
#define stepmask_raw v7
#define stepmask stepmask_raw##.16b
#define halfmask_raw v8
#define adder_scratch v9

#define string x0
#define length x1
#define out x2
#define scratch_reg x3

.section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
.build_version ios, 12, 0
.globl    _aggregate
.p2align    2

_aggregate:
// load masks
movi vrepquote, #0x22

mov scratch_reg, 0x4080
movk scratch_reg, 0x1020, lsl 16
movk scratch_reg, 0x0408, lsl 32
movk scratch_reg, 0x0201, lsl 48
dup stepmask_raw.2d, scratch_reg

mov scratch_reg, 0xffff
movk scratch_reg, 0xffff, lsl 16
movk scratch_reg, 0xffff, lsl 32
movk scratch_reg, 0xffff, lsl 48

ins halfmask_raw.d[0], x31 // zero it out
ins halfmask_raw.d[1], scratch_reg

iter:
subs length, length, #16
ldur q2, [string]

cmeq vchrs0, vchrs0, vrepquote
and vchrs0, vchrs0, stepmask

movi.16b vadds_raw, #0
addv b0, vchrs0_raw.8b
and vchrs0, vchrs0, halfmask_raw.16b
addv b9, vchrs0
ins vadds_raw.b[1], adder_scratch.b[0]

str h0, [out]
add out, out, #2
add string, string, #16
b.hi iter
ret
```

Comment: Is `subs` really at fault or is the profiler blaming it incorrectly?

Comment: I'm betting this is a branch mispredict

Comment: How are you measuring this? Which profiler, which processor?

Answer (score 0):

The profiler provides an address in the binary as the location. In this case it's the `iter` label. But the label, of course, doesn't occupy space in the binary itself, so the address is that of the `subs` instruction, which is the destination of the branch at the end of your loop.

This suggests that the bottleneck in your program is indeed the branch, probably due to branch mispredicts. This is probably good news as it means your SIMD logic is not holding up your processing.

An interesting experiment is to try your function on different lengths of input. Does the profile change considerably?

Comment: No, the profile does not change very much. How can I reduce mispredictions? Also, I'm surprised it would mispredict. In my benchmark, I run it for an array of about 5,000 chars, so wouldn't it quickly start predicting that `b.hi` will be true?

Comment: Maybe it's not mispredicts. It's just that the branch needs to be executed, instructions need to be fetched etc. If unrolling didn't help then mispredicts are probably not the problem. The important thing is that the memory accesses and the SIMD instructions are not the bottleneck

Comment: I see, so what would I investigate next?

Comment: I'd say unrolling the loop, but you've already tried that. The other thing to try to increase performance is to align the loop. Some processors prefer branch destinations to be aligned. For example, the Cortex-A57 software optimisation guide (http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.uan0015b/Cortex_A57_Software_Optimization_Guide_external.pdf) recommends quadword alignment. Depending on the processor you're targeting, try using a `p2align` directive (if you're using `gas` as an assembler)

Comment: I use `.p2align 2` in the sample above, but based on what you said I also tried 4 and 8. I also added a couple `nop` instructions so that the jump would go from `0x80` to `0x30`, but none of these things helped.